# linux http proxy with web accelerator

Tags: raspbian, proxy

I am looking for a suggestion for which http proxy to use. I am planning on installing an http proxy in my network but then I thought that perhaps I should get one with tcp/web acceleration. I have quite a few devices on the network and don't want to have to install a separate accelerator on every device, so I want to put it on one server so that all devices get the benefit. I have been looking into it and I have not been able to find one. I was planning on getting squid to use as a http proxy, it does not support compression, prefetching, preemptively resolve hostnames or ad removal. The ad removal is not that important to me but it would be nice. It is also not a web accelerator other than it caches. Does anyone know of a service that can handle that? Are there maybe modules to squid that do those things? I do not know squid really at all nor have I actually used it. If someone does have a suggestion is that software compatible with webmin? The distribution that I will be using is raspbian, most services are available on it but though I'd mention it. have a nice day.